# useContext return getState undefined in component children

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a problem accessing the context within a child component, which is returning me undefined

router.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    let { url } = this.props.match

return (
  <div className='container-main'>
    <Menu baseUrl={url} />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${url}/tasksVision`} component={Home} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
   )
  }
}

export default Home
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { PedidosProvider } from '../../../context/components/pedidos-pedidosVolume';
import Modal from './modal';

const Pedido = (props) => (
    <PedidosProvider {...props}>
        <Modal />
    </PedidosProvider>
)

export default Pedido;
```

modal.js

this const "test" does works when called on that component

```
const Modal = () => {
    const {
       test
    } = useContext(PedidosContext)

    return (
        <div>
          {test}          //this is working
          <Orders/>
        </div>
       )
}
```

orders.js

this const "test" does not work when called on that component

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { PedidosContext } from '../../../context/components/pedidos-pedidosVolume'

const Teste = () => {
    const { test } = useContext(PedidosContext) // this return: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
    return (
        <h1>{test}</h1>
    )
}
    
export default Teste
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the context API a lot but I think you are getting an error because you are destructuring the PedidosContext.

```
const { test } = useContext(PedidosContext)
```

should be

```
const test = useContext(PedidosContext)
```

Altough it can be that my answer is not what you are looking for. However, in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) it is used the same way as I just described.